# Can't run queue example from Red Hat

Tags: redhat, amq

I can't run a simple queue example from Red Hat AMQ. It displays the following error:

```
Non-resolvable parent POM for org.apache.activemq.examples:artemis-examples:2.10.0.redhat-00004: Failure to find org.apache.activemq:artemis-pom:pom:2.10.0.redhat-00004 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ org.apache.activemq.examples:artemis-examples:2.10.0.redhat-00004, /opt/redhat/amq-broker/amq-broker-7.5.0/examples/pom.xml, line 23, column 12 -> [Help 2]
```

And here's my pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
distributed with this work for additional information
regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
"License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
software distributed under the License is distributed on an
"AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
specific language governing permissions and limitations
under the License.
-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

   <parent>
      <groupId>org.apache.activemq.examples.broker</groupId>
      <artifactId>jms-examples</artifactId>
      <version>2.10.0.redhat-00004</version>
   </parent>

   <artifactId>queue</artifactId>
   <packaging>jar</packaging>
   <name>ActiveMQ Artemis JMS Queue Example</name>

   <properties>
      <activemq.basedir>${project.basedir}/../../../..</activemq.basedir>
 </properties>

   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
         <artifactId>artemis-jms-client-all</artifactId>
         <version>${project.version}</version>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>

   <build>
      <plugins>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
            <artifactId>artemis-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
               <execution>
                  <id>create</id>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>create</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                     <ignore>${noServer}</ignore>
                  </configuration>
               </execution>
               <execution>
                  <id>start</id>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>cli</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                     <spawn>true</spawn>
                     <ignore>${noServer}</ignore>
                     <testURI>tcp://localhost:61616</testURI>
                     <args>
                        <param>run</param>
                     </args>
                  </configuration>
               </execution>
               <execution>
                  <id>runClient</id>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>runClient</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                     <clientClass>org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.example.QueueExample</clientClass>
                  </configuration>
               </execution>
               <execution>
                  <id>stop</id>
                  <goals>
                     <goal>cli</goal>
                  </goals>
                  <configuration>
                     <ignore>${noServer}</ignore>
                     <args>
                        <param>stop</param>
                     </args>
                  </configuration>
               </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
               <dependency>
                  <groupId>org.apache.activemq.examples.broker</groupId>
                  <artifactId>queue</artifactId>
                  <version>${project.version}</version>
               </dependency>
            </dependencies>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
         </plugin>
      </plugins>
   </build>
   <profiles>
      <profile>
         <id>release</id>
         <build>
            <plugins>
               <plugin>
                  <groupId>com.vladsch.flexmark</groupId>
                  <artifactId>markdown-page-generator-plugin</artifactId>
               </plugin>
            </plugins>
         </build>
      </profile>
   </profiles>
</project>
```

And if you please know what's wrong, reply with the pom.xml updated. It's easier for me to solve the problem instead of just saying what I am supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing really wrong with the `pom.xml` per se. The message from Maven explains the issue fairly well:

```
Non-resolvable parent POM for org.apache.activemq.examples:artemis-examples:2.10.0.redhat-00004: Failure to find org.apache.activemq:artemis-pom:pom:2.10.0.redhat-00004 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2
```

This is saying that Maven can't find the parent POM for `org.apache.activemq.examples:artemis-examples:2.10.0.redhat-00004` (i.e. `org.apache.activemq:artemis-pom:pom:2.10.0.redhat-00004`) at https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2.

The resource can't be resolved because Red Hat specific Maven artifacts for AMQ are not pushed to Maven central. Instead you must login to the Red Hat Customer Portal and download the specific Maven repository that matches the AMQ broker version you're using. Instructions on how to use the repository will be in the downloaded repository archive.